# Numbered equations with additional text

Tags: math-mode, equations, numbering

I would like use the following enumeration of equations:

```
               x+y=z                            (1.1) some text
```

Where this enumeration is, say, given on the right side of equation. It consists of a numerical part which will automatically increase to (1.2) for the next equation and a fixed part containing some short text.

Comment: Just a suggestion: add the text to the left of the equation tag (the number). Readers can quicly browse through equations if the numbering is consistemtly placed in the same location (tipically flushed to a margin); extra text replacing the expected position for the numbering could be distracting

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the way the equation numbers are printed by modifying the definition of `\tagform@`.

This one prints the text in the right margin:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)\rlap{ some text}}}
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)\rlap{ some text}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{test}
\noindent X\hrulefill X
\begin{equation}
  a=b
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  c=d
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer the text not being in the right margin, change the redefinition to:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr) some text}}
\makeatother
```

and you'll get

[image]