# Numbered equations with additional text part 2

Tags: math-mode, equations

I would like to have numerated equations with some additional text added, where the numbering automatically increases for any next equation, with the possibility to add a different text for any equation (or no text). This question is partially answered under "Numbered equations with additional text" Something like this (ennumereation should be flushed to the right):

a=b                                        (1.1) some text

The next equation is is just numbered with no additional text

b=c                                        (1.2)

And this one has a different text

a=c                                        (1.3) some other text

Comment: It seems like you may have two accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: For reference, part 1 is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163737/numbered-equations-with-additional-text/

Answer (score 1):

The following might suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\add@text}{}
\newcommand{\tagaddtext}[1]{\gdef\add@text{#1\gdef\add@text{}}}% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764
\renewcommand{\tagform@}[1]{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)\rlap{~\add@text}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{test}
\noindent X\hrulefill X
\begin{equation}
  a=b \tagaddtext{something}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  c=d
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \tagaddtext{stuff}\\
  g(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The above example provides `\tagaddtext{<stuff>}` that you can use to add `<stuff>` to the right of the regular equation numbering marker.

Comment: one problem with this is that, if you need to print it, it might run right off the edge of the paper.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Absolutely true... I'll insert it in a zero-height, `[t]`op-aligned `\parbox` maybe, but I'm not sure how much `<stuff>` the OP wants in these annotations.