# Unit column in table with square brackets and siunitx

Tags: tables, math-mode, siunitx, columns

The header might be a bit weird. But I would like to add a specified column type that is reserved to units.

For instance, take a look at the following working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
    \newcolumntype{M}{>{$} l <{$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
R &= \sqrt{Q\: \frac{t}{\pi\: b\: n_{eff}}}
\end{align}

Where:\\

\begin{tabular}{M |l l}
R & Radius for BNBO & $\left[\si{\meter}\right]$ \\
Q & Extraction rate & $\left[\si{\cubic\meter\per\second}\right]$ \\
t & Time frame for BNBO & $\left[\si{\second}\right]$ \\
b & Aquifer thickness & $\left[\si{\meter}\right]$ \\
n_{eff} & Effective porosity & $\left[\si{--}\right]$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This should return this:[image: Columns test]

Now, what I would like to do, is to be free of writing all the stuff before and after the unit. This means that instead of writing

```
$\left[\si{\cubic\meter\per\second}\right]$
```

I would simply just write

```
\cubic\meter\per\second
```

as the only thing for the unit description of Q.

As you can see, I have already defined a column with respect to math, the column M. I have tried to do it in a similar way with units, which returned an error. The code I tried was

```
\newcolumntype{U}{>{$\left[\si{ l <}\right]$}}
```

Inserting U into the third column and deleting math and `siunitx` environment, like this

```
\begin{tabular}{M |l U}
    R & Radius for BNBO & \meter \\
    Q & Extraction rate & \cubic\meter\per\second \\
    t & Time frame for BNBO & \si{\second \\
    b & Aquifer thickness & meter \\
    n_{eff} & Effective porosity & - \\
\end{tabular}
```

the following error occurs:

```
Package array Error: >{..} at wrong position: token ignored. \begin{tabular}{M |l U}
```

I can't really figure it out. Please help me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with the help of the `collcell` package (loads `array`).

Just define your column as

```
\newcolumntype{U}{>{$[\collectcell\si} l <{\endcollectcell]$}}
```

and you're done.

MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{collcell} % loads array
    \newcolumntype{M}{>{$} l <{$}}
    \newcolumntype{U}{>{$[\collectcell\si} l <{\endcollectcell]$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
R = \sqrt{Q\: \frac{t}{\pi\: b\: n_{eff}}}
\end{equation}

Where:\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{M |l U}
    R & Radius for BNBO & \meter\\
    Q & Extraction rate & \cubic\meter\per\second\\
    t & Time frame for BNBO & \second\\
    b & Aquifer thickness & \meter\\
    n_{\textit{eff}} & Effective porosity & -\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Notice that the right way to add some spacing is not `\\` but something like `\bigskip`. Also, usign `align` when there is nothing to align is not the best choice, use `equation` instead.

If you really want, but I would avoid it, you can even add `\left` and `\right`

```
\newcolumntype{U}{>{$\left[\collectcell\si} l <{\endcollectcell\right]$}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :) That works great! And then I can just avoid the array package, since collcell loads it anyway? :)

Comment: @AndreasLøvgaard You're welcome. And, yes, `collcell` loads `array`, so you can avoid loading it yourself.

Comment: The brackets `[]` usually mean abstract dimensions (say “lenght/time”); for units, parentheses `()` or, better, nothing should be used.

Answer (score 8):

1. Please unlearn your habit of using `\left ... \right` all over
2. Drop the `[]`, they do nothing to the interpretation of that column
3. use the `s` column, and in that column just write say `\meter`

In code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{$} c <{$}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{M l s } %|
\toprule
\mc{Variable} & Meaning & \mc{Unit} \\
\midrule
R & Radius for BNBO & \meter\\
Q & Extraction rate & \cubic\meter\per\second\\
t & Time frame for BNBO & \second\\
b & Aquifer thickness & \meter\\
n_{\textup{eff}} & Effective porosity & \mc{---} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 4. Variables that are physical quantities shouldn't have prescribed units; if the equation and values are dimensionally consistent, the equation holds.

Comment: Since I intend to use the column type with no headlines (e.g. Unit headline), I prefer the square brackets []. And I would really like new column type with that.
But thank you for the tip of using s column.

Comment: I still think it is better for the reader. What if the person reading it does not know the meaning of `[m]`?

Comment: @AndreasLøvgaard Unnecessary cryptic writing. There is nothing wrong with a header line. Your *Where:* does not serve anything in your example in that regard also.

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks for this discussion; where I used to study, it was actually a formal convention that units should be put in square brackets `[]`, which is how I came upon this question - so to me, it is not cryptic at all. @PaulGessler - no one disputes whether the equation will hold; but if I see the equation for the first time (and if I'm, say, slightly dumb), are you saying that it would be easier for me to understand the dimensional relationships by _not_ having the units spelled out?

Answer (score 4):

You add no meaning with the units in brackets; in my opinion it's even wrong, as usually brackets denote abstract dimensions, such as “length·time<sup>–1</sup>” or “force·length”.

The `s` column type is what you're looking for. I also removed all `\:` spacing commands, which are wrong, and set “eff” in upright type.

Note also that `Where:\bigskip` would allow a page break after it.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcolumntype{M}{>{$} l <{$}}
\newcommand{\eff}{\textrm{eff}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
R = \sqrt{Q \frac{t}{\pi b n_{\eff}}}
\end{equation}
Where:\\*[\bigskipamount]
\begin{tabular}{M l s}
R & Radius for BNBO & \meter\\
Q & Extraction rate & \cubic\meter\per\second\\
t & Time frame for BNBO & \second\\
b & Aquifer thickness & \meter\\
n_{\eff} & Effective porosity & \multicolumn{1}{c}{--}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Voted, but I'll repeat my comment: Variables that are physical quantities shouldn't have prescribed units; if the equation and values are dimensionally consistent, the equation holds.

Answer (score 1):

To my test is more appropriate for explanation of variables of some equation to use list environment than table. For example something as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
    \usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\mathentrylabel}[1]{%
     \makebox[\labelwidth][l]{\parbox[t]{\labelwidth}{%
                                         \raggedleft$#1$:}
                               }}
\newenvironment{mathentry}[1]%
    {\begin{list}{}{%
        \renewcommand{\makelabel}{\mathentrylabel}%
        \settowidth{\labelwidth}{\textsf{\quad#1}}%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth + \labelsep}
        \setlength{\parsep}{0\baselineskip}
    }}%
    {\end{list}}

        \begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{equation}
R = \sqrt{Q \frac{t}{\pi b n_{\text{eff}}} }
    \end{equation}
Where:
    \begin{mathentry}{$n_{\text{eff}}$}
\item[R]                Radius for BNBO     [\si{\meter}]
\item[Q]                Extraction rate     [\si{\cubic\meter\per\second}]
\item[t]                Time frame for BNBO [\si{\second}]
\item[b]                Aquifer thickness   [\si{\meter}]
\item[n_{\text{eff}}]   Effective porosity
    \end{mathentry}
        \end{document}
```

With this approach the units given in brackets probably seems more natural as in table.
[image]