# Is it possible to make two tags for the same equation?

Tags: cross-referencing, align

In the screenshot below, I want to add another tag, namely `by (a)` for the equation tagged already by `(1)`. How can I achieve that?

[image]

Here is my code concerning this part:

```
\begin{align*}
\\&= 2 A\bigl( v^1,v^2,v^3,v^4 \bigr) 
+ 2 A\bigl( v^1,v^4,v^3,v^2 \bigr)   
+ 2 A\bigl( v^1,v^2,v^1,v^4  \bigr)   + 2 A\bigl(v^1,v^2,v^3,v^2  \bigr) \\
&\phantom{{}= }+ 2 A\bigl(v^1,v^4,v^3,v^4  \bigr) + 2 A\bigl( v^3,v^2,v^3,v^4 \bigr). \tag{1}
\end{align*}
```

Note: My preamble is the default one and I am using the `article` document class.

Comment: Do you mean tagging it such that you obtain (1)(a)?

Comment: Something like that. Precisely, `by (a)` then a little space and then `(1)` .

Comment: What do you mean by `default preamble`?

Comment: You may give a look to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166580/82917) and the questions linked there.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a tag, but a textual explanation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
x&=y
\\
&= 2 A( v^1,v^2,v^3,v^4 )
+ 2 A( v^1,v^4,v^3,v^2 )  \\
&\quad+ 2 A( v^1,v^2,v^1,v^4  )
+ 2 A(v^1,v^2,v^3,v^2  ) \\
&\quad+ 2 A(v^1,v^4,v^3,v^4  ) + 2 A( v^3,v^2,v^3,v^4 ).
&&\text{by (a)} \tag{1}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn’t it rather be `...v^4),&&\text{by (a).}`?  (I mean, the punctuation.)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Probably; I just took the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a single tag with two things inside.  Modifying `\theequation` is simpler, but treats the outer parentheses differently from the inner.  The last version does not include both parts in the `\ref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\flalignbalance}{\hphantom{(\theequation)}\hskip\mintagsep}

\begin{document}
This should link to \ref{test}, \eqref{test2} and \ref{test3}
\vfill
This uses \verb$\tag*$
\begin{equation}
\stepcounter{equation}\label{test}
x=a \tag*{(a) (\theequation)}
\end{equation}
\vfill
\bgroup
\renewcommand{\theequation}{a) (\arabic{equation}}
This reformats \verb$\theequation$.
\begin{equation}\label{test2}
y=b
\end{equation}
\egroup
\vfill
This uses \texttt{flalign}.  \verb$\flalignbalance$ is used to center the equation.
\begin{flalign}\label{test3}
\flalignbalance&& z&=c &\llap{(a)}
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```