# How to align left and central on the same lines

Tags: equations

I want to have something as follows: A word is left aligned, then an equation is central aligned in the same line

```
word              [\centering some equation]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You can use the `flalign` environment (from `amsmath`).

Comment: It should be noted that flalign is affected by the equation number and the size of each field.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365894/is-it-possible-to-make-two-tags-for-the-same-equation/365943?s=1|0.0000#365943 for how to address the problem.

Comment: @Bernard Won't that left-align it?

Comment: Centred relative to the rest of the line or centred relative to the whole line? Please provide a small, compilable document illustrating your set up.

Answer (score 1):

One way of centering in the line, in the rest of the line or in any space between the text:

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\setlength\parskip{2em}
\def\reference{\dotfill center \dotfill}
\begin{document}
\reference\par
\makebox[0pt][l]{Word}\hfil\(2+3\)\par% solution A
$\hphantom{Word}$\reference\par
Word\hfil\(2+3\)\par% solution B
\leavevmode\phantom{Word}\reference\phantom{Anotherword}\par% reference
Word\hfill\(2+3\)\hfill Anotherword\par % solution C
\end{document}
```