# The "correct" or recommended way of using siunitx in math mode

Tags: math-mode, siunitx

I want to have equations with units. For example, the Hooke's law in physics.
There are 4 non-trivial ways as follows.

## First Option

```
% first option
\documentclass[border=1cm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx,esvect}
\begin{document}
\SI[parse-numbers=false]{\vv F=-kx\hat{x}}{\newton}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Second Option (cannot be compiled)

```
% second option
\documentclass[border=1cm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx,esvect}
\begin{document}
\SI[parse-numbers=true]{$\vv F=-kx\hat{x}$}{\newton}
\end{document}
```

## Third Option

```
% third option
\documentclass[border=1cm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx,esvect}
\begin{document}
$\vv F=-kx\hat{x}\,\si{\newton}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Fourth Option

```
% fourth option
\documentclass[border=1cm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx,esvect}
\begin{document}
$\vv F=-kx\hat{x}$~\si{\newton}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Because the first one is not properly rendered in math font and the second one cannot be compiled, I have to choose between the last two. So which one is the recommended one?

Comment: According to point #12 in [this page](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/checklist.html "this page"), your first solution is the correct one.

Comment: Shouldn't that mean that #3 is the correct one?  But it'd be nice to have something official explaining why.  Or to figure out how to make #2 compile, so that siunitx can properly take care of the spacing, since that's one of its jobs.

Comment: I would recommend _not_ putting units with your equations, or at the very least not as is. Right now N looks like a variable or multiplicative factor, such that the units of this force would be square newtons. Consider also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166610/173134

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the [documentation](ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) of `siunitx` (section 4.3):

> Very often, numbers and units are given together. Formally, the value of a quantity is the product of the number and the unit, the space being regarded as a multiplication sign. The `\SI` macro combes the functionality of `\num` and `\si`, and makes this both possible and easy.

It follows that your first and second option are not supposed to give satisfactory results because the first argument of `\SI` is designed to take numbers but not formulas. Thus, you are right with your third and fourth option, to change to the use of `\si` to typeset the formula and connect it manually to the unit.

I assume you want the same space between the formula and the unit as one would get from `\SI` between a number and the unit. The space in `\SI` is given by the option `number-unit-product`. According to table 24 of the documentation, this option's default value is `\,`. Thus, the "recommended" way is your option 3:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx,esvect}
\begin{document}
$\vv F=-kx\hat{x}\,\si{\newton}$
\end{document}
```

One more quote from section 4.3 of the documentation:

> The formatting methods will work with both math and text mode.

So it doesn't really matter whether you put `\si` inside or outside of math-mode, as long as you choose the appropriate space.