# Undefined control sequence error while using \tagaddtext

Tags: undefined, control

```
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
 H(m_X) &= \sqrt{\frac{8\pi G}{3} \rho(x=1)}\\ %removed big before rho from here from here.

\rho(x=1) &= \epsilon / c^2 &= \frac{g_*\pi^2}{30}\frac{K_b^4T_m^4}{\hbar^3c^5}\\
    \tagaddtext{\Big(T_m = T(x=1)\Big)}`\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

So here is my code. Iam using the packages `delimset` and `amsmath`.

My error is.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ..._b^4T_m^4}{\hbar ^3c^5} \tagaddtext 
                                                  {\Big (T_m = T(x=1)\Big )}...
l.223 \end{split}
```

The thing that I found was that by commenting on the `\tagaddtext`. The file runs perfectly. So I would like to know whats causing the issue. Thanks in advance and I am a beginner in LaTeX. Started like around 5 days back.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have multiple mixed constructions in that section.

Thus it is difficult to guess your desired output.

You have wrapped the equation matter in {split} but I don't see any split defined (or any need for one)

You have included alignment markers &= suggesting you simply need the equations in a basic {align}

The problem with \tagaddtext is that it is an undefined command that comes from an answer by Werner to [Numbered equations with additional text part 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163854/numbered-equations-with-additional-text-part-2) so  needs to be defined the same way in the preamble and as text when in a math environment it needs as a minimum $...$. Adding all the above comments together I get this as a working solution with the given snippet.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{delimset,amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\add@text}{}
\newcommand{\tagaddtext}[1]{\gdef\add@text{#1\gdef\add@text{}}}% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764
\renewcommand{\tagform@}[1]{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)\rlap{~\add@text}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%\begin{equation}
\begin{align}
%\begin{split}
H(m_X) &= \sqrt{\frac{8\pi G}{3} \rho(x=1)}\\
\rho(x=1) &= \epsilon / c^2 \\
&= \frac{g_*\pi^2}{30}\frac{K_b^4T_m^4}{\hbar^3c^5} \tagaddtext{$\Bigl(T_m = T(x=1)\Bigr)$}
%\end{split}
\end{align}
%\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry I should have left a note in the edit, yes it makes the ( mathopen rather than mathord but since in this case the (...) is the entire math list it doesn't actually make any difference, but it's simpler to follow a simple rule of never using the versions without r/l.